# Cannot use parameter for MySQL limit in Pentaho

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I am using Pentaho to create reports. When I try to use a parameter for limiting the number of rows it throw an error. The query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT topics_dim.topicName, dictationLength, originalDate 
FROM dictations
INNER JOIN topics_dim ON dictations.topicId = topics_dim.topicId
WHERE dictations.originalDate between ${StartDate} AND ${EndDate} 
ORDER BY dictations.dictationLength DESC
LIMIT ${Record_limit};
```

I am declaring `Record_limit` as a number and selection type is text box. I tried changing the data type and the selection type but no use.

Comment: StartDate and EndDate works well? Is this PRD or spoon?

Comment: Yes, StartDate and EndDate works fine, and when ever i give a number instead of paramert the limit is also working fine.

Comment: I created a quick one now with `value type` as `Number` and it worked. leaving all the other fields empty except `Name` , `Label` , `Display Type` and it a text box.  Is your `parameter name`  has correct spellings? `Record_limit`?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried to set the 'Format' like # when datatype is integer or number? maybe there were some more characters generated as it should be.

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon I have tried the same sequence and I have double checked the names, can you paste your sample code.

Comment: @Seb I haven't tried doing it, will try it.

Comment: `select * from table limit ${Record_limit}` If you can attach the prpt I can try to reproduce it here.

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon Record_limit is working if I don't use any other conditions in where clause but not when its written like above